# I get: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, but I can't see anything missing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have tried everything and noticed that the function will only work if I delete all arguments after @item.Host.

I occasionally get

> SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

if I try to tinker with arguments order:

```
<a href="#" onclick="sideBarMenu('@item.Type', '@item.TimeUtc.ToLongTimeString()', '@item.Host', '@item.Message', '@item.Source', '@item.User', '@item.AllXml')">



function sideBarMenu(type, time, host, message, source, user, xml) { 
    document.getElementById("sidebar2").style.right = ("-10px")
    document.getElementById("side-bar-icon").classList.add("rotate")
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-header")[0].innerHTML = type;
    document.getElementsByClassName("time-for-logs")[0].innerHTML =   time;
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-host")[0].innerHTML = host;
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-message")[0].innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-source")[0].innerHTML = source;
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-user")[0].innerHTML = user;
    document.getElementsByClassName("card-text")[0].innerHTML = xml;
}
```

Code should pass all the values to the JS function without any error.

Comment: I'm guessing (it is a guess because you haven't provided a [mcve]) that one of your razor varibales contains a line break or a `'` or some other illegal character. If you want to pass information this way you need to sanitise your inputs

Comment: you are not closing anchor tag . 

<a href="#" onclick="sideBarMenu('@item.Type', '@item.TimeUtc.ToLongTimeString()', '@item.Host', '@item.Message', '@item.Source', '@item.User', '@item.AllXml')"> side Bar Menu Click
</a>

Comment: I think that's just an example @virendernehra

Comment: It'd help if you included your raw JS, without the razor

Comment: Sorry it's my bad, I am an extreme beginner in coding - I do close the <a> tag but I haven't include that in the code, which I defienetly should

Comment: I checked after closing the anchor tag and it was calling the function

Comment: The code you show here simply doesn't have the error you are seeing. You need to show us a [mre] or we will have to close the question.

Comment: I simply don't know how to either include raw js, or give an reproductive example.

all that data is coming from Model, <a> tag is within foreach.

Comment: My guess is that one of the properties of `item` contains a newline that you haven't escaped, you can't just dump values like that directly on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my issue I had to use C# Utility to encode my JS

many of you have pointed my in to right direction, even that I haven't include a lot of code.

solution was to wrap my value like this:

```
'@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Type)'
```